# How to get output from a function in Java?

Tags: java, function, methods, output, call

I have a main program that call this function :

```
public static void eucDist(int i, double data[][], double weight[][]) {

    double sum = 0; 
    double min = 10000;

    for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
        for (int k=0; k<5; k++) {
            sum = sum + Math.pow((weight[k][j] - data[i][k]),2);
        }

        double dist = Math.sqrt(sum);

        if(dist < min) {
            min = dist;
            int saveCol = j;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get **saveCol** in the main program?

If I put

```
public int getsaveCol(){
    return saveCol;
}
```

so I can call *saveCOl* with *eucDist.saveCol* but it returns an error.

Comment: Post your main class/method.

Comment: are all those methods (not functions) in the same class???

Comment: `saveCol` only exists within the `eucDist` method, you cannot access it from outside (and that method doesn't return anything either)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: I think yes

Comment: @UnholySheep: so how can I get saveCol to my main program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return it:

```
public static int eucDist(int i, double data[][], double weight[][]) {

    double sum = 0; 
    double min = 10000;
    int saveCol = -1;

    for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
        for (int k=0; k<5; k++) {
            sum = sum + Math.pow((weight[k][j] - data[i][k]),2);
        }

        double dist = Math.sqrt(sum);

        if(dist < min) {
            min = dist;
            saveCol = j;
        }
    }
    return saveCol;
}
```

Comment: why `int saveCol` have to be -1 ?

Comment: @newcomers it must be initialized, otherwise there will be a compiler error. I chose -1 because it's an invalid array index,

Comment: thanks for your answer @Maurice Perry but every iteration, `saveCol` only return 0 then it ruins my program

Comment: @newcomers It will return 0 if the minimum dist is at j=0, otherwise, it will return something else.

Comment: unfortunately, the problem comes from my bad data that always bring the minimum dist in j=0 ,, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could return `saveCol` from `eucDist`.

```
public static int eucDist(int i, double data[][], double weight[][]) {

    double sum = 0; 
    double min = 10000;
    int saveCol = 0;

    for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
        for (int k=0; k<5; k++) {
            sum = sum + Math.pow((weight[k][j] - data[i][k]),2);
        }

        double dist = Math.sqrt(sum);

        if(dist < min) {
            min = dist;
            saveCol = j;
        }
    }

    return saveCol;
}
```

Comment: then how do I call the function so I get thesaveCol in my main program?

Comment: thanks your answer really works MonsieurBon but every iteration saveCol only return 0 then it ruins my program

Comment: @newcomers that means dist < min occurs either in the first iteration or never. Initialize saveCol to -1 and you will know which one it is.